# QFileSystemWatcher не отслеживает изменения файлов

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Создаю на "куче" QFileSystemWatcher для отслеживания изменения содержимого файлов. Сами пути поторые я добавляю в QFileSystemWatcher выглядят так:

```
E:/tmp0.txt
E:/tmp1.txt
E:/tmp2.txt
E:/tmp3.txt
```

А вот сам код который не работает:

```
this->file_watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);
l_s->Add("Add files");
for(int i=0; i<this->files.count(); i++)
{
    if(this->file_watcher->addPath(this->files.at(i)))
    {
        this->l_s->Add("true 1");
    }
    else
    {
        this->l_s->Add("false 0");
    }

}
QObject::connect(this->file_watcher,
                 SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)),
                 this,
                 SLOT(ChangedHandle(QString)));
```

Слот:

```
public slots:
    void ChangedHandle(QString);
```

В логе функция `if(this->file_watcher->addPath(this->files.at(i)))` всегда возвращает true

P.S. Пишу в файл через `notepad++` и сохраняю

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте другой редактор для изменения. Возможно, notepad++ создает при записи новый файл, подменяя старый. Или добавьте отслеживание директории